# Displaying current date on views

Tags: 7, views, display-suite

Is there a way to display the current date on views? I just realized that I couldn't use global tokens nor could I get custom date created on Display Suite on views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter).
2. Got to Configuration > Text Formats and enable Token Filter ("Replace Tokens") for a text format.
3. In your view add Header/Footer "Global: Text Area" and choose the text format from step 2.
4. In the text area write `[current-date:short]` and optionally check `[x] Display even if view has no result`.

Source: https://ffwagency.com/digital-strategies-blog/how-add-current-date-view-drupal-7

---

To do this in the fields section use [Advanced Text Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_text_formatter), which allows you to choose a text format for "Global: Custom text" fields.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1417266#comment-12245061

Comment: Hi @leymannx thanks a lot for the response. I didn't think about adding it to header footer, thank you for the tip. But I actually need it in the field section, is there a way for it as well

Comment: Hey @Efe, updated answer.

Comment: @leymannx there is no option for Global: Custom text, only for Text content type fields.

Comment: @user3108268 – This answer is for Drupal 7.

Comment: @leymannx yes, my response is also to Drupal 7. Advanced Text Formatter does not work for Global: Custom text, there is no text formatter option at all. However the formatter appears for text fields.